# Asserting Write Data for the Register File and also writing into it at the same positive clock edge ? Isn't this violating hold time conditions?

Tags: assembly, cpu-architecture, riscv

I was going through the latest edition of the Patterson Hennessy book on RISC-V, Comp Org And design (2020), when I came across this diagram. This specific pipeline does not have any hazard detection or forwarding. ***Also for my specific query, the issue of hazards do not even matter as this would be a concern even if I were feeding exactly 1 instruction into my program***.

[image: excerpt from book]

The register file in the ID (instruction decode) stage behaves as follows for write. It can accept new data only when Write Enable is 1 and the clock is positive edge.

The image annotation states the register file is written with the x2 data only at clock cycle 5 (CC5). But based on the above considerations, wouldn't that cause a possible ***hold time violation***? For reference, I have drawn the timing diagram at CC5 in red, showing what the register file would see at the positive edge at clock cycle 5(CC5).Thus, after CC5's positive clock edge , you are only allowing the correct data (Write Enable=1, the correct x2 data) too percolate at the register file. So only on the next clock edge (CC6) is this data being entered into the register file.

Could anyone clarify this for me?  Is this an error in the book?

**EDIT**: I should have specifically stated my main concern here is hold time violations. And this concern remains even if you have a special register file that writes in positive clock edge and reads in negative clock edge. This  also has nothing to do with the issue of pipeline hazards. This would be a problem to me even if I were running only one instruction in my program. Here's why:
Assuming I am only running exactly the first sub instruction in my pipeline(so nothing related to hazards), this is what happens at the positive edge of CC5: The WriteEnable=1 and the WriteData are transferred from MEM stage to the register file in WB stage. And at the exact same time instance(i.e. positive clock edge CC5), you are also inserting this writeData into the register file. But if this is true, then aren't you at rish of possible Hold Time violations at the register file? Because the register file itself is composed of flip flops which need to follow hold time constraints. You can potentially make this happen fine but you are at risk of data corruption

Comment: Isn't the diagram intended to show how data hazards arise? The caption says that the blue lines going back in (clock) time are hazards. They probably started with a naive pipeline and will correct it in the next chapters? BTW I think you can read `x2` already in CC5, has it is written in the first half (rising edge) of the clock cycle.

Comment: The caption explicitly says that data written in the first half-cycle can be read in the 2nd half-cycle.  So that explains what happens in clock cycle #5.  This is a common design for register files, especially in simple in-order pipelines.

Comment: Hi @MargaretBloom, I should have properly titled my question with respect to my actual  concern in this pipeline scheme. My question had nothing to do with hazards and would have even persisted if I were running just 1 instruction through my pipeline. It was more of a conceptual question regarding hold time violations in the register file and I have accordingly edited it ow to reflect my concern.

Comment: Presumably the register file *isn't* based on clocked flip-flops that sample their input on the clock edge.  Hold-time would be a problem if you built it that way.  Instead it's more likely an SRAM array addressed by the register-number, designed so it works as long as the inputs have time to settle before the next clock edge.

Answer (score 4):

The updated value for `x2` is available at the very beginning of cycle 5, at the rising clock edge — unlike other operations, there is nothing to compute, so the value is available very early in the cycle (i.e. immediately).

Further, the ID stage doesn't itself actually use the register values that it reads in that cycle: it simply forwards them to the next stage.  So, the ID stage doesn't need the updated value until the very end of the clock cycle, where it will be captured in a pipeline register (and made available to the ALU for the next clock cycle).

There are at least two designs that allow reading the updated value in the same clock.

One such design is that the store completes in the first half of the cycle and the ID read takes place in the 2nd half of the cycle — and another way of saying this same thing is that the ID stage output (captured at the end of the cycle in the ID/EX pipeline register) settles to the updated register value by the end of the cycle, even if it temporarily reads/sees the stale value early in the cycle.

(Cycle timing has to allow for settling of values as initial output values are likely incorrect in some way or another, and propagation takes some time.  With enough time, the right answer emerges and is stable.  Here, the desired value is selected (mux'ed) and copied, several times (e.g. into the register, then out of the register); though this copying of each bit a few times is quite a bit simpler than addition, for example, which has to cascade the carry in some way, meaning that the MSB takes more hardware to compute than the LSB, which is not the case with the register file simple copy operations.)

The other such design is that there is an internal forward inside the register file, which can make the updated value available even in the first half of the cycle.

> So only on the next clock edge (CC6) is this data being entered into the register file.

No, the data is being entered into the register file during clock cycle 5.

The Write Enable control signal, along with the target register number (`x2`) comes from decode (ID) of the instruction in cycle 2, and is forwarded from ID to EX to MEM and finally to WB where they are used.

Like the updated value intended for `x2`, the Write Enable control signal is also available at very the beginning of the clock cycle 5, so everything for the register write to occur (Write Enable control signal, target register number, value to write) is ready to go at the rising edge (very beginning) of cycle 5.  By the end of cycle 5 (and start of cycle 6), the updated/written value will have propagated across the register file circuitry so as to become the register read value(s) for the `add` instruction in ID in cycle 5 that reads/sources `x2`.

---

The falling clock edge can be used to separate the 1st half of the cycle from the 2nd half (so as to start some new activity half way through the cycle), and while that is sometimes done, that approach is not necessary here as the circuitry will naturally settle to the proper values without using extra/falling clock edges, and also without being the critical/slowest path (which determines the max clock rate).

Comment: So if I am reading you right, this is what happens at the positive edge of CC5:
The WriteEnable=1 and  the WriteData are transferred from MEM stage to the register file in WB stage. And at the exact same time instance(i.e. positive clock edge CC5), you are also inserting this writeData into the register file. 
But if this is true, then aren't you at rish of possible Hold Time violations at the register file? Because the register file itself is composed of flip flops which need to follow hold time constraints. You can potentially make this happen fine but you are at risk of data corruption

Comment: There is the pipeline register and also the register file.  Both will have both setup and hold time requirements depending on process technology, but these durations are small compared to an entire clock cycle.